# Where Endorsing policy is stored?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I'm new to Hyperledger Fabric.
Can any one tell me where the endorsing policy is stored in Hyperledger Fabric?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify (or modify) an endorsement policy for a chaincode within the context of a channel, it is stored in the [configuration block](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/configtx.html#configuration-updates) for that channel by the orderer.

From the Hyperledger Fabric 1.1 documentation:

> When the CONFIG_UPDATE is received, the orderer computes the resulting
>   CONFIG by doing the following:
>
> 1. Verifies the channel_id and read_set. All elements in the read_set must exist at the given versions.
> 2. Computes the update set by collecting all elements in the write_set which do not appear at the same version in the read_set.
> 3. Verifies that each element in the update set increments the version number of the element update by exactly 1.
> 4. Verifies that the signature set attached to the ConfigUpdateEnvelope satisfies the mod_policy for each element in the
>      update set.
> 5. Computes a new complete version of the config by applying the update set to the current config.
> 6. Writes the new config into a ConfigEnvelope which includes the CONFIG_UPDATE as the last_update field and the new config encoded in
>      the config field, along with the incremented sequence value.
> 7. Writes the new ConfigEnvelope into a Envelope of type CONFIG, and ultimately writes this as the sole transaction in a new configuration
>      block.
>
> When the peer (or any other receiver for Deliver) receives this
>   configuration block, it should verify that the config was
>   appropriately validated by applying the last_update message to the
>   current config and verifying that the orderer-computed config field
>   contains the correct new configuration.

Comment: Thank you christo4ferris, my understanding is that the endorsement policy is stored in conf.block of that channel and it is stored by the orderer right.